# App Content not filling simulator window

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

Just having an Xcode issue that I'm sure is tied to some setting I can't find. Im my storyboard, my content fills the entire view (i.e a background image), but then when I run my app in the iPhone 6 simulator, the background image and all the content don't fill the entire screen. There is white space to the right of and below the content on the simulated "screen".

When I run the app in the iPhone 5 simulator, this isn't an issue and it fills the entire simulated view.

So, what did I miss? I want to make my app work on all models of the iPhone.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Without seeing anything you did, it's hard to guess. Start with what constraints you have set on the background image view.

Comment: Did you add any constraints? Do you have size classes turned on in IB?

Comment: There are no constraints set, and size classes are turned off (the box is not checked)

Comment: What simulated size of the viewControllers do you use in your storyboard? If you have set that to 4" then thats the reason...

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Comment: @LinusG. how do I see the simulated size of my viewControllers?

Comment: @Nerrolken no I haven't yet, I was out of the country for a week, back at it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this, and I guess you are using View Size as Inferred or iPhone4 Inch in Attribute Inspector.

First way is to use AutoLayout at Storyboard to add Constraint.

If you don't want to use this, you should at least set the Autoresizing at Size Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

"White space to the right of and below the content" sounds like there are scroll bars being displayed in your window.  The iPhone 6 simulator is a different size, as well, which would account for them not being there on the iPhone 5 sim.

[image: for example]

Have you tried going to the Home Screen (Shift + Command + H) in your simulator, and seeing if the white bars remain?  On my computer, the white bars are always visible.  Annoying, yes, but they don't cover anything or hide any part of the view.  It's just a bit of white padding on two sides.

Comment: thanks for the response, but no it's not scroll bars. It's a solid chunk of white space about 4x thicker than that